# how do I set bash to show autocomplete options on a single tab press?

Tags: bash

If bash autocomplete finds multiple files, it only autocompletes the common part and I have to press TAB again to have it show me a list of them.

I know there's a way to make this happen on the first TAB press, but how?

In other words, current behaviour:

```
$ cd fTAB
```

turns into:

```
$ cd foo
```

another TAB gets me a list "foobar foobiz".

What I want it to get that list on the first TAB.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try adding

```
set show-all-if-ambiguous on
```

to your `~/.inputrc`, like so:

```
echo "set show-all-if-ambiguous on" >> ~/.inputrc
```

btw: `man bash` is your friend - searching it for `completion` yields above answer.